# how to align lines to the left side with sed or perl one line liner

Tags: linux, bash, sed, perl

we have the following file

how alignment lines to the left side with sed or perl one line liner

```
more conf.env

# Extra ssh options.  Empty by default.
    export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=5 -o SendEnv=HADOOP_CONF_DIR"

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
  export HADOOP_LOG_DIR={{hdfs_log_dir_prefix}}/$USER

# History server logs
               export HADOOP_MAPRED_LOG_DIR={{mapred_log_dir_prefix}}/$USER

# Where log files are stored in the secure data environment.
         export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR={{hdfs_log_dir_prefix}}/$HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER

   # File naming remote slave hosts.  $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves by default.
# export HADOOP_SLAVES=${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/slaves
```

expected results

```
more conf.env

# Extra ssh options.  Empty by default.
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=5 -o SendEnv=HADOOP_CONF_DIR"

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR={{hdfs_log_dir_prefix}}/$USER

# History server logs
export HADOOP_MAPRED_LOG_DIR={{mapred_log_dir_prefix}}/$USER

# Where log files are stored in the secure data environment.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR={{hdfs_log_dir_prefix}}/$HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER

# File naming remote slave hosts.  $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves by default.
# export HADOOP_SLAVES=${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/slaves
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will delete all spaces and tabs at the beginning of every line:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

where

- `^` matches the beginning of a line
- `[ \t]` matches a space or a tab
- `*` makes the previous `[…]` block work zero or more times, as many times as it can (so it can match multiple spaces and/or tabs)

The whole `s/…//` command replaces `…` pattern (`^[ \t]*` in this case) with nothing.

Example use:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//' <input.txt >output.txt
```

or in place (note `-i` is not required by POSIX):

```
sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//' file.txt
```